# How can i set an icon for my own file extension

Tags: windows, icons, file-association

i register my file extension in windows with "ftype" and "assoc", this works. now i have the bad looking default icon, how can i change this icon??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.[extension]` default key contains a `REG_SZ` string, that is the name of the next key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[that_string]\DefaultIcon` default key ("@") contains this:
`[path_to_icon_file],[zero_based_index]`

Example:

```
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
     @="MyTextFile"
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyTextFile\DefaultIcon
     @="C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe,2"
```

This way, all .txt files will use the **third** icon from the Explorer executable.